# Select unique characters present in one list in a list of lists

Tags: r

I am trying to filter all the characters that are present in `a` that are not present in `b` and `c`. I want to do this from the list `l`.

```
a<-c("A", "B", "C", "D", "E")
b<-c("A", "E", "I", "O", "U")
c<-c("H", "E", "L", "L", "O")
l<-list(a,b,c)
```

So the answer should be `BCD`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can try the code below

```
> d <- table(stack(setNames(l, seq_along(l))))

> row.names(d)[d[, 1] == 1 & rowSums(d) == 1]
[1] "B" "C" "D"
``
```

Comment: Worked like a charm, thanks!

Answer (score 1):

We could use `setdiff` as well

```
setdiff(l[[1]], unlist(l[-1]))
[1] "B" "C" "D"
```